# Find the value of $a^{2015}+b^{2015}+c^{2015}+d^{2015}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

$OMITS$ $2015$, $Indonesian$

> If the complex numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ satisfy
>
> $a+b+c+d=3$
>
> $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=5$
>
> $a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3=3$
>
> $a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4=9$
>
> Find the value of $a^{2015}+b^{2015}+c^{2015}+d^{2015}$

I think i can find the value $a$, $b$, $c,$ and $d$ and subtitute it to the question, but i think too difficult and complicated

this is the related question, but i need more coherent, clear, and complete solution

[System of equations in a,b,c,d](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345940/system-of-equations-in-a-b-c-d)

I Just Junior High School Student

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345940/system-of-equations-in-a-b-c-d

Comment: In addition, why not to use the explicit solutions. Since the equations are symmetric in $a,b,c,d$, we may assume that $d=-1,c=2,b=2-a$ and $a=1+i$ or $a=1-i$. No problem!

Comment: Yess, but i need a more coherent, clear and complete solution

Comment: This is coherent, clear and complete. You should give it a try!